# How to find out how libraries work together?

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, reverse-engineering

I'm tasked to replicate functionality from an existing application. This application relies on .NET managed assemblies accessible from C#. I can import those DLLs in my new C# project but there is no documentation on how to use them.

Yes, this is labeled as an "SDK", but does not contain examples or documentation. Any pointers on how I should proceed?

I thought about creating stub assemblies and monitor their usage from the original application but this involves a lot of code.  Is there maybe a tool could do it for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is the best way to do that. You can see what calls what and examine the dlls in a good and easy way.

You can also try [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

They both are great tools for inspecting managed dlls

Comment: If the dll's are managed then the main exe is probably .net, too.
Look how they use their own api.

Comment: Good advice.  Don't forget to disassemble the calling code to see how the API is used in context.

Comment: Yes, Reflector is the way to go, assuming the assemblies are not obfuscated. It can export a disassembled assembly to a Visual Studio project, which you can then build, add to your solution, and use a VS Test project to write invocations of the classes/methods in the legacy assembly. It's actually a lot of fun when you get the hang of it!